# Changing text into Select dropdown list - jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, input

This maybe a really simple question but for some reason my code isn't working.

Basically, if a user clicks on a piece of text which has the container class of .valueSD, I want the text to change into a select box so they can update the value of it.

Here is an example of what I did:

```
$('.valueSD').click(function(){
    $('.valueSD').html( function(){
        var monthDrop = '<td class="valueSD">'+
            '<select name="date-month">'+
                '<option name="01">January</option>'+
                '<option name="02">February</option>'+
                '<option name="03">March</option>'+
                '<option name="04">April</option>'+
                '<option name="05">May</option>'+
                '<option name="06">June</option>'+
                '<option name="07">July</option>'+
                '<option name="08">August</option>'+
                '<option name="09">September</option>'+
                '<option name="10">October</option>'+
                '<option name="11">November</option>'+
                '<option name="12">December</option>'+
            '</select>'+
        '</td>';

        console.log( monthDrop );

        return monthDrop;   
    });
});
```

For some reason it doesn't work though.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You can pass a string directly to the `html()` function, like `$('#valueSD').html('<td class... etc etc');`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tV2Pf/1/ There is the JSFiddle :)

Comment: Sorry that seems to work fine. I have no idea why it doens't work locally. Thanks for your time all!

Comment: make sure you check for js errors locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine..
but the only thing that you need to do is remove the bounded event click else the dropdown will be unselectable just add the code.

`$(this).unbind("click");` in the callback function that handles the click event

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tV2Pf/2/)**

Comment: I think I love you xD I was looking for a while to see why that wasn't working :P Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for an ID inside a function , when the TD has a class,

```
 $('.valueSD').click(function(){
$('.valueSD').html( 
    '<td class="valueSD">'+
        '<select name="date-month">'+
            '<option name="01">January</option>'+
            '<option name="02">February</option>'+
            '<option name="03">March</option>'+
            '<option name="04">April</option>'+
            '<option name="05">May</option>'+
            '<option name="06">June</option>'+
            '<option name="07">July</option>'+
            '<option name="08">August</option>'+
            '<option name="09">September</option>'+
            '<option name="10">October</option>'+
            '<option name="11">November</option>'+
            '<option name="12">December</option>'+
        '</select>'+
    '</td>'  ); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this

```
$('.valueSD').click(function(){
    $(this).html( function(){
        var monthDrop = '<td class="valueSD">'+
            '<select name="date-month">'+
                '<option name="01">January</option>'+
                '<option name="02">February</option>'+
                '<option name="03">March</option>'+
                '<option name="04">April</option>'+
                '<option name="05">May</option>'+
                '<option name="06">June</option>'+
                '<option name="07">July</option>'+
                '<option name="08">August</option>'+
                '<option name="09">September</option>'+
                '<option name="10">October</option>'+
                '<option name="11">November</option>'+
                '<option name="12">December</option>'+
            '</select>'+
        '</td>';

        console.log( monthDrop );

        return monthDrop;   
    });
});
```